# Matplotlib display error - narrow bars and distorted axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Im a novice at this but have managed to put some code together to make a simple bar chart from a csv. I have two sets of data and I can plot one of them ok but when plotting the other set (which is an almost identical dataset) it doesn't look right. The data is basically two columns, one with frequency values in and another with text in. The text is the bin range for that frequency and is is written like [10. 20.]. To plot this data I read it in as a string and take the first value, converting it to a float (see code) which works great to give me two lists of values!!

I then take these two lists, one frequency and one 'bins' and plot them but I end up with really narrow bars (lines basically) and a frequency where the values are displayed by 1e^7 (i.e. 3 rather than 30000000), however the x-axis is displayed ok.

my code is:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inputfile = 'filename'

values = []
bins = []

fh = open(inputfile, 'r+')
for line in fh:
    values.append(float(line.split(',')[0]))
    bins.append(float(line.split(',')[1].replace('[','').replace(']','').strip().split(' ')[0]))

ticks = np.arange(0, 105000, 5000)

plot = plt.bar(bins, values, color='b', alpha=1, width=1)

plt.xlabel('distance (m)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xticks(ticks, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

I would post a picture of my plot but I don't have enough rep points.

My other data is almost identical to this and works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that bins and values contain the numbers you expect them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're setting the width to the bars to 1, but specifying locations that are very widely spaced.

For example, it sounds like you're doing something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977) # Generate same random numbers each time

bins = np.arange(0, 10000, 100)
values = 3e7 * np.random.random(100)

plt.bar(bins, values, width=1)
plt.margins(0.05, 0) % Just for nicer display

plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem is that you're specifying `width=1`. Presumably, you'd rather have the bars take up the full width of the bin.

If you have regularly spaced bins, then just specify their spacing.  (e.g. `width = 1000`, etc).

If they're not regularly spaced, then do something like:

```
# From looking at your code, "bins" and "values" are the same length.
# Therefore, the width of the last (or first) bar is undefined.
# We'll assume that the width of the last bar is the same as the one before it
diff = np.diff(bins)
widths = np.hstack([diff, diff[-1]])
```

And then plot with `plt.bar(bins, values, width=widths)`

[image]

Finally, if you don't want scientific notation to be used for large values, the easiest thing to do is set the `axes.formatter.limits` rc parameter to something larger.  (By default anything `>= 1e7` will be displayed using scientific notation.)

As a complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977)

# Generate data
bins = np.arange(0, 10000, 100)
values = 3e7 * np.random.random(100)

# Don't use scientific notation
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = [-100, 100]

# Plot...
plt.bar(bins, values, width=100)
plt.margins(0.05, 0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem lay in specifying the width as you suggested, I took it to be a range of 0-1 when really it was 1000 that I needed. Also the plt.rcParams solved my y axis issue. I would up-vote it but I need more points first. Thanks